# Although I set the location of the hamburger menu button in the Wordpress theme, it appears in different places on the main page and on other pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using Konte Wordpress theme on my website. I adjusted the position of the hamburger menu icon like the photos below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHdxO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4cjp.png)

But for example, although it looks the way I want on the product pages, it looks like this on the main page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHSO6.png)

It needs to be look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOR4y.png)

What can be the problem?